# Configuring Visual Studio 2008 to use log4cxx in programs/libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, log4cxx

I am a beginner in C++. I am compiling my school project which uses log4cxx. Luckily i found a already built version for visual c++ 2008 in [this site](http://www.dreamcubes.com/b2/software-development/28/log4cxx-for-win32-with-vs2005/).

After downloading the files, I did the following

**Tools->Options->VC++Directories->Library Files**, add path to Release_Shared directory for linking necessary libraries

**Tools->Options->VC++Directories->Include Files**, add path to src/main/include

But even after this I am getting errors like, 'logError' identifier not found 
"ERROR" undeclared identifier. Clearly something is missing.

I have seen somewhere I am supposed to do something with the .dll files, but not sure what it is. Can somebody help me with this, or point me to a place where there are step-by-step instructions for setting up this sort of configuration? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The note in your link:

> To use the static link log4cxx library, the macro LOG4CXX_STATIC MUST be defined in your projects preprocessor, otherwise your compilation will suffer unresolved linking error.

[Preprocessor Definitions in VS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

or use

```
#define LOG4CXX_STATIC
```

before header include